# Can a Descriptor change type in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, descriptor

I'm trying to make descriptor which can change return type in typescript but I don't know how to do this.

Here is the code and what I tried:

```
function changeReturnType()
{
    return <T extends unknown>(
        target: {},
        key: string | symbol,
        descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<T>
    ) => {
        const oldValue = descriptor.value;

        return {
            ...descriptor,
            value(...argv)
            {
                // @ts-ignore
                return String(oldValue.call(target, ...argv))
            }
        }
    };
}

class Foo {
    @changeReturnType()
    square ()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

let val = new Foo().square(); // I hope ts know here is string

console.dir({
    val,
    type: typeof val,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is [currently not possible](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) in TypeScript but you may look at [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881#issuecomment-396608437) and modify hack described there to your needs (i.e. for method decorator usage).

Comment: The situation is different in linked comment. Returned type is ignored in class decorator, while in method decorator it's taken into account, so decorated method type is incompatible with original method.